# How do I add a column into a aggregate function

Tags: sql, aggregate

Here is my query:

```
SELECT 
   dateTime, 
   AVG([timeTaken]) as avgtime, 
   MAX([timeTaken]) as maxtime, 
   COUNT(*) totalcalls
FROM 
   [Logs]
WHERE 
   csUriStem = '/REST/Issues/Issues.svc/' AND 
   [dateTime] > DATEADD(MINUTE, -15, GETUTCDATE()) AND
   (csUserAgent != 'Fiddler' OR csUserAgent IS NULL)
```

I get this error when executed:

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Column 'Logs.dateTime' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

I understand why, but my question is, how do I get the associated `DateTime` to the corresponding `[MAX([timeTaken]) as maxtime]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so aggregate functions like `AVG`, `MAX`, and `COUNT` will require some sort of `GROUP BY` if there are other fields in the `SELECT` list. This is how they know what *subset* to operate on. So what you would need to do, to get this to *run*, is something like this:

```
SELECT dateTime,
    AVG([timeTaken]) as avgtime,
    MAX([timeTaken]) as maxtime,
    COUNT(*) totalcalls
FROM [Logs]
WHERE 
    csUriStem = '/REST/Issues/Issues.svc/' AND 
    [dateTime] > DATEADD(MINUTE, -15, GETUTCDATE()) AND
    (csUserAgent != 'Fiddler' OR csUserAgent IS NULL)
GROUP BY dateTime
```

However, that may, *or may not*, be what you want. This is going to perform the `AVG`, `MAX`, and `COUNT` *over* every grouping of `dateTime`.

However, this grouping of `dateTime` is probably illogical; you probably want something like this:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), dateTime, 101) AS groupDate,
    AVG([timeTaken]) as avgtime,
    MAX([timeTaken]) as maxtime,
    COUNT(*) totalcalls
FROM [Logs]
WHERE 
    csUriStem = '/REST/Issues/Issues.svc/' AND 
    [dateTime] > DATEADD(MINUTE, -15, GETUTCDATE()) AND
    (csUserAgent != 'Fiddler' OR csUserAgent IS NULL)
GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), dateTime, 101)
```

That will format that grouping date by `mm/dd/yy`.

To further consider what's actually going on with aggregate functions, if you *didn't* have any additional fields:

```
SELECT AVG([timeTaken]) as avgtime,
    MAX([timeTaken]) as maxtime,
    COUNT(*) totalcalls
FROM [Logs]
WHERE 
    csUriStem = '/REST/Issues/Issues.svc/' AND 
    [dateTime] > DATEADD(MINUTE, -15, GETUTCDATE()) AND
    (csUserAgent != 'Fiddler' OR csUserAgent IS NULL)
```

it still operates over a *group.* That *group* just happens to be the *entire* result set.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include it in a group by clause

Something like this.

```
SELECT 
    dateTime, 
    AVG([timeTaken]) as avgtime, 
    MAX([timeTaken]) as maxtime, 
    COUNT(*) totalcalls
  FROM 
    [Logs]
  WHERE
    csUriStem = '/REST/Issues/Issues.svc/' AND 
    [dateTime] > DATEADD(MINUTE, -15, GETUTCDATE()) AND
    (csUserAgent != 'Fiddler' OR csUserAgent IS NULL)
  GROUP BY
    dateTime;
```

Note if you want information on the average and max seperately then you need to split up the query into two separate queries. Then merge them after.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the dateTime column in the group by OR choose `avg` / `max` / `min` depending on your requirements.

```
 SELECT dateTime, AVG([timeTaken]) as avgtime, MAX([timeTaken]) as maxtime, COUNT(*) totalcalls
      FROM [Logs]
      WHERE 
        csUriStem = '/REST/Issues/Issues.svc/' AND 
        [dateTime] > DATEADD(MINUTE, -15, GETUTCDATE()) AND
        (csUserAgent != 'Fiddler' OR csUserAgent IS NULL)
      GROUP BY dateTime
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want one row and you want it for the maximum value of `DateTime`, then you can do this using aggregation, `order by`, and `top`:

```
SELECT TOP 1 dateTime, AVG([timeTaken]) as avgtime, 
       MAX([timeTaken]) as maxtime, COUNT(*) totalcalls
FROM [Logs]
WHERE csUriStem = '/REST/Issues/Issues.svc/' AND 
      [dateTime] > DATEADD(MINUTE, -15, GETUTCDATE()) AND
      (csUserAgent != 'Fiddler' OR csUserAgent IS NULL)
GROUP BY dateTime
order by dateTime desc;
```